# Include TVS in low current battery powered circuit?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, transient, tvs

I'm designing a circuit powered by two alkaline cells in series with a voltage of 2-3.2V. After being fused this is going through the boost converter MCP1640B with constant 3V3 output.

The maximum load on the boost converter is about 300mA pulsed to a SIM7000A chip transmitting an LTE message.

Is it worthwhile to include a TVS across the battery rails to protect against transients? Or would it just be a waste of money/space on the PCB? I saw a source which said to include a TVS in an automotive battery-powered circuit, but that was because the load of the motors is inductive and is known to create transients.

Comment: If there is no other power source besides the two cells you do not need a TVS. Are you sure the SIM7000A will function correctly all the way down to 2V? No need to reply just double-check it.

Comment: Also, 300 mA will cause a lot of voltage sag in a AA battery. Worse in AAA. So keep that in mind. You may want to disable operation when the non-pulse voltage is around 2.5V or so, to make sure the 300mA pulse doesn't pull the voltage below 2V.

Comment: I'm putting my batteries through a boost with constant 3V3 output. The boost converter I'm using is MCP1640B. Edited the question to include that information.

Comment: According to the datasheet of Duracell Coppertop AA and AAA, the ESR of both is on the order of 100mohm. At 300mA that will only chop down on the order of 0.01V. Or is the ESR a strong function of current?

Comment: Well, first of all the battery current will be greater than the boost output current. Second of all, the ESR may not be measured exactly the way you would want it to be. You need to know, when you have a step pulse in output current, how far will the voltage fall during the pulse? It may be more like 300mOhms, and worse if it is cold or the battery is near end of discharge. Just be aware of it. I spent 9 years of my life designing alkaline battery powered electronic devices. I do promise you that the voltage will sag a lot under load, and recover more than you think when load is removed.

Comment: Check this out: https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/alkaline_appman.pdf
Make sure to read the part about pulse discharging throughout battery life. Pages 7-10.

Comment: Also, just to correct your arithmetic, 300mA * 100mOhm is actually 30 mV (0.03) not 10 mV (0.01) as you said. I agree that 30mV is not much and if that was all you would get then it wouldn't be a problem. But as I noted, it may be quite a bit more than that as the battery discharges, and the current may be more than 300mA as you initially stated.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is no other power source, there is no reason to include a TVS diode. Alkaline batteries are unlikely to be harmed by ESD or similar, and there doesn't seem to be any other possible source of transient voltages in your design.

However, you should make sure you have enough input capacitance for your boost converter.